# pathlib glob with absolute paths

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I want to glob with absolute path similar to the posed problem/solution in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311703/globbing-absolute-paths-with-pathlib](https://stackoverflow.com).
The only difference is that the provided absolute path may have a different anchor than `"/"`.
Using glob works fine and is concise

```py
import glob
pathname = "\\\\www.abc.def\\fs\\foo\\bar/*"
glob.glob(pathname)
```

However, trying to achieve this using `pathlib` is not really concise anymore.

My solution so far reads

```py
Path(Path(pathname).anchor).glob(Path(pathname).relative_to(Path(pathname).anchor).as_posix())
```

The approach here is to extract the anchor and glob relative to this anchor with the rest of the string.

Is there a better solution using `pathlib`?